# SNMP library for android

Tags: android, android-ndk, snmp

Is it possible to create let's say an App that can run SNMP get and set query under any android version Or is there SNMP library for Android development?
Regards, Paul

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the Java SNMP project which is, I quote (the project website)

> is an open-source implementation of the SNMP protocol as a Java package. It provides support for basic SNMP client and agent operations as defined in SNMP versions 1 and 2 (excluding the security model proposed as part of SNMP version 2, which was never widely accept or deployed). The package provides a mechanism for "getting and setting" SNMP object identifier (OID) values through a simple communication interface, and represents SNMP structures and datatypes as corresponding Java objects.

The URL for the project is http://gicl.cs.drexel.edu/people/sevy/snmp/ and you'll find all the required details on that page.